# Error when authenticating with Firebase OauthToken method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook, ionic-framework, firebase

I am trying to authenticate a user in my ionic app using the `authWithOAuthToken()` method in Firebase. I am getting this error -> `{"code":"INVALID_CREDENTIALS","details":"{\"providerErrorInfo\":{}}"}` with my firebase ref, when I try with another firebase ref, it works.

In [Firebase Error Listing](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html#section-full-error), `INVALID CREDENTIALS` means

> The specified authentication credentials are invalid. This may occur when credentials are malformed or expired.

But I am not passing any credential to the method

```
var Ref = new Firebase('https://<firebase-ref>.firebaseio.com');
Ref.authWithOAuthToken('facebook', '<facebook token>', function(error, authData) {
  if (error) {
    console.log('Login Failed!', JSON.stringify(error));
  } else {
    console.log('Authenticated successfully with payload:', authData);
  }
});
```

Anybody encountered this before?

Comment: The error message means that the information in the token you pass is invalid. How did you get the value that you're passing in `'<firebase token>'`?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I got the token by authenticating a user via the fb sdk. What surprises me is that is works for another firebase ref.

Comment: Having exactly the same problem... I just see one difference from your code to mine `<firebase token>` I think you probably mean `<facebook token>` right?

Comment: Yes @weilah corrected the question, were you able to fix it?

Comment: not yet, but if I find the solution I will post it here!

Answer (score 0):

Go to Facebook Tab inside Login & Auth in firebase project, Copy and paste Credentials from [your facebook developer app](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/) and try running your app, if you have already entered your details, make sure they are correct , if it still doesn't work check by creating a new facebook developer app and again enter the details in firebase